# Returning an EntityObject to work with

Tags: entity-framework

I'm not sure if I should work directly with the `EntityObject`, or if I should make som wrapper methods for selecting, updating and deleting EntityObjects? I would like to use the last option, but I can't really figure out how to return an `EntityObject` (so I still can call `context.SaveChanges();`) and not for example a `List<Worker>` (which is stupid since I can't make changes to the Workers in the list and then easily submit the chages to the database.

For example, I have a `Worker` table. I could get a worker by using my context:

```
var worker = context.Worker.Where(w => w.WorkerID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or, I could create a wrapper method:

```
public static RETURNTYPE GetWorkerByID(int id, context)
{
    var worker = context.Worker.Where(w => w.WorkerID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
    return worker;
}
```

What kind of returntype should I work with, if I still wish to work with the context (allowing me to alter the data)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a wrapper type you will not be able to use it with context anymore. Using wrapper means that your return type will represent a new instance filled from the entity object and when you push that instance back you will again need to create / fill entity object to work with.

Have you considered using POCOs (EF 4.0 and newer only)? That would solve your problem because there is on `EntityObject` base class.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really familiar with POCOs, but I have read a little about them. The thing is that I'm under pressure to complete the project in due time, so if it is timeconsuming to setup POCOs, then I will not do it. But regarding a wrapper, your answer just elaborated on my concerns :)